# Screenshoting many webpages

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot

I would like to take screenshot of many pages using phantomjs.

The problem is how to deal if I have more pages than 1000 because at the present moment following code crashes phantomjs:

This is an example of **aobj**:

```
var aobj = '[{"kb":21.047829999999976,"jb":52.174250000000015,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.047997078651633,"jb":52.17421235955058,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.048164157303404,"jb":52.17417471910114,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.04833123595506,"jb":52.1741370786517,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.048498314606718,"jb":52.174099438202255,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.04866539325849,"jb":52.17406179775282,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.048832471910146,"jb":52.17402415730338,"ff":110.16456426650427},{"kb":21.048999550561803,"jb":52.173986516853944,"ff":110.16456426650427}]'
```

... and more

Rest of the code:

```
aobj = JSON.parse(aobj);

function tes_par(nrr,jbb,kkb,hhf)
{
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 480 };
console.log(nrr);
page.open('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location='+jbb+','+kkb+'&pitch=-0.760&sensor=false&heading='+hhf, function () 
{
    page.render(nrr + '.png');      
});
}

for (var i=0;i<aobj.length;i++)
{
tes_par(i,aobj[i].jb,aobj[i].kb,aobj[i].ff);
}
```

I assume that this is because JS can run one code at a time, so it consumes all resources, but I have no idea how to wait for **page.open** and **page.render** and wait if there are more than 1000 calls of these functions.

I also tried to use setTimeout, but again without success:

```
aobj = JSON.parse(aobj);

function tes_par(nrr,jbb,kkb,hhf)
{
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 480 };
console.log(nrr);
page.open('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location='+jbb+','+kkb+'&pitch=-0.760&sensor=false&heading='+hhf, function () 
{
    page.render(nrr + '.png');      
});
}


function aa_bb(ii)
{
var jj=0;
(ii+500<aobj.length) ? jj=ii+500 : jj=aobj.length;
for (var i=ii;i<jj;i++)
{
tes_par(i,aobj[i].jb,aobj[i].kb,aobj[i].ff);
}
};

aa_bb(1);
setTimeout(function(){aa_bb(501)},120000);
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't worked in phantom js. You are running this script in node right? can you use some kind of queue so that you can pass the request one at a time?

Comment: Yes, I have been thinking about this. Unfortunately, my implementations of the queue don't work:(.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `page.close()` after each render. The [docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/close.html) mention reusing the same object without closing can prevent garbage collection.

Comment: Same results - before page.close() is executed phantomjs crashes because of too many page.open() calls.

Answer (score 2):

See [Using Multiple page.open in Single Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996732/phantomjs-using-multiple-page-open-in-single-script/17000930#17000930). The basic idea is that you open the next page at the end of the function passed to the previous page open. Otherwise, you are opening a bunch of pages at once, and mayhem ensues.

```
aobj = JSON.parse(aobj);
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 600, height: 480 };

function tes_par(nrr,jbb,kkb,hhf)
{
    console.log(nrr);
    page.open(
        'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=640x480&location='+jbb+','+kkb+'&pitch=-0.760&sensor=false&heading='+hhf,
        function () 
        {
            page.render(nrr + '.png');
            setTimeout(function(){next_thingie(nrr+1);},100);
        }
    );
}

function next_thingie(i)
{
    if(i>=aobj.length){return;}
    tes_par(i,aobj[i].jb,aobj[i].kb,aobj[i].ff);
}

next_thingie(0);
```

**Update**

The code above has been changed from the earlier version, after I reviewed my own code (which works) and found I had not applied it correctly to this problem. Changes include:

1. Create page only once.
2. Make recursive call for next page **within** `page.open` function.
3. Apply a little timeout to help PhantomJS catch its breath.

This approach works for me in capturing about 300 screenshots from about 80 files.

Comment: It doesn't work;/. console.log(nrr) prints only "0" and then crashes.

Comment: `i` was being incremented in the wrong place and never reached. See my edit.

Comment: Something around i=1200 I get _[CRITICAL] QThread::start: Failed to create thread_ and phantomjs crashes. Moreover, it iterates over `i` so fast that phantomjs doesn't have time to save png file (for sure).