# PhantomJs doesn't resize the window

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using this code:
var width = 1024;
var height = 768;

and page.viewportSize = {width: width, height: height}; im using before  page.open . But this doesn't work.
The full code you can watch in my another question right here - 
[Faking the Referer Header in PhantomJS is doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42472913/faking-the-referer-header-in-phantomjs-is-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment72086829_42472913)

here is the code:

```
var width = 1024;
var height = 768;
var page = require('webpage').create();
//referal massive
var reff = ["https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/","https://google.com","https://youtube.com","https://twitter.com/"];
//random massive
var randreff = Math.floor(Math.random() * (reff.length));
//reffer
page.customHeaders = {
  "Referer": (reff[randreff])
};
//console refer
console.log(reff[randreff]);
var urls = ['http://test.com/','http://test.com/2017/02/blog-post.html','http://test.com/'];
var i = 0;
function OpenPage(){
    setTimeout(function(){
            page.open(urls[i], function(status) {
                    if (status == 'success') {
                page.viewportSize = {width: width, height: height};
                    page.render('example' + i + '.png');
            }
            i++;
            if(i <= urls.length - 1){ 
                OpenPage();
            }else{
               phantom.exit();
            }
        });
    },5000);
}
OpenPage();
```

- Resolution doesn't work and referrals doesn't work =(

Comment: Please post the full code here. The code from your other question is missing `page.viewportSize = {width: width, height: height};`.

Comment: The full code indeed does matter. For example, code in one of the similar questions revealed the viewport size was set after page had already been opened - thus too late for it to work.

Comment: I have edit my post and add the full code. page.viewportSize - doesn't work (in analytics I see only my PC screen resolution, not the resolution I have set in the code) and referrals doesn't work too....=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`page.render()` renders whole page regardless of viewport size, it's normal behaviour ... what you need is `page.clipRect()`... something like:

```
page.viewportSize = {width: width, height: height};
```

The above should be defined before `page.open()` - tells a page to render the way like the window would be of given size

To render image of given size, you need to:

```
page.clipRect = {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    height: viewportSize.height,
    width: viewportSize.width
  };

page.render(...);
```